# How to reduce the calculation of $\Vert f \Vert$ to $\Vert u \Vert$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, dual-spaces

I know that for every $f \in H^{-1}(a,b)$ there exists a function $u_f \in L^2(a,b)$ such that $$\langle f,v\rangle = -∫_a^bu_f(x)v'(x) \ dx, \ \ \  v\in H_0^1(a,b).$$

How can I reduce the calculation of $\|f\|_{-1,2}$ to the calculation of 
$\|u_f\|_{H_0^2(a,b)}$ 
where $\|f \|_{-1,2}:= \sup_{v \in H^1_0(a,b)\backslash\{0\}}\frac{|\langle f,v\rangle|}{\vert v\vert_{H_0^1(a,b)}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the uniqueness of $u_f$ you need some additional condition (as $u_f$ is defined up to a constant).

Let us take $\int_a^b u_f(x) dx=0$.

- Then using C-S, for all $v \in H^1_0$:
  $$\left|\langle f,v \rangle \right| =\left|\int_a^b u_f(x) v'(x) dx \right| \leq \|u_f\|_{L^2} \|v'\|_{L^2} =\|u_f\|_{L^2} \|v\|_{H^1_0} $$
  so taking the $\sup$:
  $$\|f\|_{-1,2} \leq \|u_f\|_{L^2}$$
- To show the equality let $v \in H^1_0$ such that:
  $$v'=u_f$$
  (here the condition $\int_a^b u_f(x) dx=0$ is important to have the right boundaries conditions, and if your functions are complex consider $v'=\overline{u_f}$).
  Then:
  $$\left|\langle f,v \rangle \right|=\int_a^b |u_f|^2(x) dx =\|u_f\|^2_{L^2}$$
  and:
  $$\|v\|_{H^1_0}=\|v'\|_{L^2}=\|u_f\|_{L^2}$$
  so:
  $$\frac{\left|\langle f,v \rangle \right|}{\|v\|_{H^1_0}}=\|u_f\|_{L^2}$$

To conclude you have:
$$\|f\|_{-1,2}=\|u_f\|_{L^2}$$
where $u_f$ is chosen such that $\int_a^b u_f(x) dx=0$ or for any $u_f$:
$$\|f\|_{-1,2}=\left\|u_f-\int_a^b u_f(x) dx\right\|_{L^2}$$

---

**Edit**: why we can take $\int_a^b u_f(x) dx=0$.

Let $u_f \in L^2$ such that $$\langle f,v\rangle = -\int_a^b u_f(x)v'(x) \ dx, \ \ \forall  v\in H_0^1(a,b) \tag{1}$$ and let $C$ be any constant.

Then for all $v \in H_0^1(a,b)$ you have:
$$\int_a^b Cv'(x) dx=v(b)-v(a)=0$$
so:
$$-\int_a^b (u_f(x)+C) v'(x) dx=-\int_a^b u_f(x) v'(x) dx-\int_a^b C v'(x) dx=\langle f ,v \rangle +0$$
i.e $u_f +C$ also satisfies $(1)$.

With the particular choice of $C=-\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b u_f(x) dx$:
$$\tilde{u_f}=u_f-\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b u_f(x) dx$$
you obtain:

- $\tilde{u_f} \in L^2$ and  $$\langle f,v\rangle = -\int_a^b \tilde{u_f}(x)v'(x) \ dx, \ \ \forall  v\in H_0^1(a,b) $$
- and:
  \begin{align}\int_a^b \tilde{u_f}(x) dx&=\int_a^b \left( u_f(x) -\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b u_f(s) ds\right) dx \\
  &=\int_a^b u_f(x) dx-(b-a) \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b u_f(s) ds =0\end{align}

so $\tilde{u_f}$ is the same as $u_f$ and has a zero mean.

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot. Just one last question: Why can we just add an arbitrary condition on $u_f$ ( chose $u_f $ such that $\int_a^bu_f(x)dx=0$)?

Comment: @Tesla You can show that if $u_f$ is a function verifying the equality then so is $u_f + C$ with $C$ a constant. More over with $u_{f,1}$ and $u_{f,2}$ two such functions you have: $$\int_a^b (u_{f,1}-u_{f,2})(x) v'(x) dx=0$$ for all $v \in H^1$ and so $u_{f,1}-u_{f,2}$ is a constant.

Thus the set of all $u_f$ is $\{u_{f,0}+C, C  \in \Bbb R \} $ where $u_{f,0}$ is any such function.

You can impose the average of $u_f$ (or others conditions) by choosing a particular $C$:
$$u_f=u_{f,0}-\int_a^b u_{f,0} (x) dx$$

Comment: @Tesla If you need it I can edit my answer to explain with more details my comment :-).

Comment: Thank you a lot, makes sense to me, although I will need to think about it again ;D

Comment: But if you have some spare time, I would appreciate some more details on that (still, I am not so sure why we can chose $u_f$ such that $\int u =0$)

Comment: @Tesla I have added some explanations in the answer. (And I have made a mistake in my previous comment it is $$u_f-\color{red}{\frac{1}{b-a}}\int_a^b u_{f,0} (x) dx$$. )

Comment: Thanks, the extended answer makes it clear for me now!